# Block a user when free trial period get's over without google play user

Tags: android, firebase

I want to implement an app in which there will be a button and when a user clicks the button the free trial period will start till the valid time given. Soon after the time get's over there will be a pop up either to subscribe or exit. and if a user subscribe then again how to implement subscription till given time and again show a pop up either to subscribe or exit.

I want the database to be firebase

I want to do it without using google play console. Is there any way to proceed???

Comment: You can do this with the use of shared preferences. You should store one variable in shared preference and store any future date in that and then compare that variable with current date every time app is opened, This way you can do what you want to do.

Comment: Any particular site which can elaborate more about this

Comment: IT won't be on any website, this is my suggestion